# WebDriver executing javascript strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Webdriver through JBehave-Web distribution (3.3.4) to test an application and I'm facing something quite strange:

I'm trying to interact with a modalPanel from Richfaces, which gave me a lot of problems because it throws ElementNotVisibleException. I solved it by using javascript:

This is the code in my page object which extends from org.jbehave.web.selenium.WebDriverPage

```
protected void changeModalPanelInputText(String elementId, String textToEnter){
    makeNonLazy();
    JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver();
    String script ="document.getElementById('" + elementId + "').value = '" + textToEnter + "';";
    je.executeScript(script);
}
```

The strange behaviour is that if I execute the test normally, it does nothing, but if I put a breakpoint in the last line (in Eclipse), select the line and execute from Eclipse (Ctrl + U), I can see the changes in the browser.

I checked the JavascriptExecutor and the WebDriver classes to see if there was any kind of buffering, but I couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I found out that putting the thread to sleep for 1 second it makes it work, so it looks some kind of race condition, but cannot find out why...

This is the way it "works", but I'm not very happy about it:

```
protected void changeModalPanelInputText(String elementId, String textToEnter){
    String script ="document.getElementById('" + elementId + "').value = '" + textToEnter + "';";
    executeJavascript(script);
}

    private void executeJavascript(String script){
    makeNonLazy();
    JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    je.executeScript(script);       
}
```

Putting the wait in any other position doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1):

First idea:

Ensure that target element is initialized and enumerable.  See if this returns `null`:

```
Object objValue = je.executeScript(
    "return document.getElementById('"+elementId+"');");
```

Since you're using `makeNonLazy()`, probably just add the target as a WebElement member of your Page Object (assuming [Page Factory](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) type of initialization in JBehave).

Second idea:

Explicitly wait for the element to be available before mutating:

```
/**
 * re-usable utility class
 */
public static class ElementAvailable implements Predicate<WebDriver> {

    private static String IS_NOT_UNDEFINED = 
        "return (typeof document.getElementById('%s') != 'undefined');";
    private final String elementId;

    private ElementAvailable(String elementId) {
        this.elementId = elementId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        Object objValue = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
                String.format(IS_NOT_UNDEFINED, elementId));
        return (objValue instanceof Boolean && ((Boolean)objValue));
    }
}

...

protected void changeModalPanelInputText(String elementId, String textToEnter){
    makeNonLazy();

    // wait at most 3 seconds before throwing an unchecked Exception
    long timeout = 3;
    (new WebDriverWait(webDriver(), timeout))
            .until(new ElementAvailable(elementId));

    // element definitely available now
    String script = String.format(
            "document.getElementById('%s').value = '%s';",
            elementId,
            textToEnter);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver()).executeScript(script);
}
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it didn't work: In the first case, I can always get the element correctly, that doesn't seem to be the problem. For the second one, adding the a wait BEFORE retrieving the element doesn't work, it only works if I put the wait AFTER retrieving the element and BEFORE executing the javascript

Comment: When you say "AFTER retrieving the element", which line of code are you referring to?

Comment: If I put the wait as you have it in your code, using the WebDriverWait it doesn't work. Doesn't give any error but it doesn't update the website. But if I add the wait just before calling executeScript method, it works